# ruby regex with address conversion

Tags: ruby, regex

```
東京都building千代田区丸の内１building２floor１number
```

to

```
東京都千代田区丸の内１-２-１
```

PS: Digits are double bytes.I have a string,that contains address. How to convert that address like above.

Comment: What more can you say about `"1 building2floor"`?  Can `"1"` and `"2"` be any numbers? Could it be `"1building 2 floor"` (note spacing)? Is the word "building" always to be matched?  Please edit to clarify. You may wish to do so with additional examples of strings that may or may not appear.

Comment: "1" ,"2" can be any number also "1building 2 floor" it can be  both (with space ,without space.

Comment: Yes, but do not attempt to clarify in comments, as not everyone may notice them. Edit your question instead. Good question, btw.

Comment: Are you trying to process 東京都千代田区丸の内１丁目２番１号? Not sure what this "building" thing is, especially not in the first part - there normally isn't anything between province and ward names.

Comment: Yes just trying to convert "丁目" ,"番","号","番地" to "-"

Comment: You will get much better answers if your examples match the real data as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question that probably should have been asked (given the clarifications in comments):

```
address.gsub(/([０-９]+)(?:丁目|番地?|号)(?=[０-９]|$)/, '\1-').sub(/-$/, '')
```

This will process any sequences of "number+location" (with "location" being lot, block, (house) number...) that is either followed by another number, or is at the end of the string, replacing the location with a dash; then removing the final dash, if there is one.

Note that this will not pick up on Japanese numbers: if you get an address like 東京都千代田区丸の内一丁目２番１号, it makes no sense to transform it to 東京都千代田区丸の内一-2-1, and converting Japanese numbers into Arabic ones is trivial up to 9 and then a bit less trivial.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: As I stated, I am working with the knowledge of real Japanese addresses, as OP confirmed that there is no "building" or "floor" or "number" actually in the text. Test on a more realistic Japanese address I provided in the comments, any of the examples in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_addressing_system), or random real Japanese addresses you find in the wild.

Comment: thank you. But there is one thing. It doesnt replace 丁目|番地?|号 etc. Can you please explain to me step by step. what should  i do.

Comment: It does for me. This is literally all I do. Are you maybe using outdated Ruby (before 1.9)? EDIT: [proof](https://repl.it/B709/0)

Comment: im using Ruby 1.9.3. What's your ruby version?

Comment: 2.2.0. It should work with 1.9+ (1.8 didn't by default use Unicode).

Answer (score 0):

```
string.gsub(/(?<=[０-９])(?:丁目|番地?|号)\b/, "-").sub(/\z/, "")
```

Comment: thank you. But there is one thing. It doesnt replace 丁目|番地?|号 etc. Can you please explain to me step by step. what should i do

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.